# Hamilton decompositions of cycle plus triangles graphs

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity, hamiltonicity

A cycle plus triangles graph is a 4-regular graph $G$ with a Hamiltonian circuit $C$ and such that the chords of $C$ induce a set of disjoint triangles (3-circuits).  A 4-regular graph $G$ has a Hamilton decomposition if its set of edges can be partitioned into two sets that induce Hamiltonian circuits in $G$.  A cycle plus triangles graph is edge 3-connected if it doesn’t have any edge 2-cuts (sets of two edges which when removed disconnect the graph).

Our question is the following

> **Question** Let $G$ be a cycle plus triangles graph which is edge 3-connected.  Is it true then that $G$ has a Hamiltonian decomposition, or is there a counterexample that might be known?

Comment: As a minor comment, a 4-regular graph which is 3-edge-connected is automatically 4-edge-connected: by counting odd-degree vertices, there cannot be a partition $V(G) = S \cup T$ with exactly 3 (or any other odd number) of edges between $S$ and $T$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you!

Comment: @MishaLavrov I couldn’t find cases of even order which are class 2 yet.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I now checked the example in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All edge 3-connected cycle plus triangles graph with 18 or fewer vertices have Hamiltonian decompositions.  However, the graph in the picture below with 21 vertices is edge 3-connected and does not have a hamiltonian decomposition.  It got derived from a counterexample to another hamiltonicity conjecture made some years ago about a class of cubic graphs (MO-graphs, cubic graphs with a chordless dominating circuit); the example was found by Brendan McKay - the derivation entails replacing dominated vertices by triangles. From 21 vertices onwards there seem to be counterexamples of every possible order.  There would seem to be a relation between hamiltonian MO-graphs and cycle plus triangles which have a hamiltonian decomposition, but we are unable to establish it at present or be more specific about it.

[image: example]